# To Check if List item exist in sharepoint List or not

Tags: sharepoint, listitem

I have to check if list item Exists in sharepoint list using C# . if it Exists i have to update(increment) "Attempt Column" by 1 . i wrote few codes.but they are not working.i need this urgent.

Comment: Where is your code that you tried?

Comment: i dont have it now...i have to rewrite it..nyways the code was from forum itself,,i tried to change few things but not worked out

Comment: Post the Code we can help. There are multiple ways you can search for List item in SharePoint

Comment: Can you post simplest way to chechk if list item exist in Sharepoint list.Would be grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to give you the code simply because you should attempt to solve it yourself first or at least explain that you have some knowledge of how you would go about it however i will help in give you a little insight.

You can do this a couple of ways

1
Get the `SPWeb object` where the item is supposed to be. Normally context of the site.

Get the list where the item is supposed to live `SPWeb object.lists[listname or guidhere]`

Loop through the list checking if anything matches in each item or even checking if the object matches the object

The other way is to use an SPQuery object

set the `SPquery.query = "YOUR CAML STATEMENT HERE"`

```
SPList<yourlist>.GetItems(SPQuery object)
```

if the above returns >0 items you have a match

Increment by one

This should give you a good starting block

cheers
Truez

Comment: SPSite site = new SPSite("Siteurl/");
SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
SPList list = web.Lists["ListName"];
SPQuery spQuery = new SPQuery();
spQuery.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='UserID' /><Value Type='Text'>USERID</Value></Eq></Where>";
        SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(spQuery);

      if (items != null)
      {
         MessageBox.Show("User Name Exists");
     
      }
      else
      {
          MessageBox.Show("not");

        }

i am new in this ..Please help me ..

Comment: i got the solution...thank you all for your replies :) ..Appriciate